# SharePoint 2019, Hide document id-column in edit form (modern)

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

We are using Document ID in our SharePoint 2019 on prem environment. Now I would like to hide the document id from displaying in the properties window when selecting a document. We are using stp-templates to create our libraries and I have added this to the field:

```
<Field ID="{0e3eaa36-165d-45d3-9451-744b513536a9}"
  Type="Text"
  DisplayName="$Resources:dlccore,DocId_ColumnName_Value;"
  Name="_dlc_DocId"
  Hidden="TRUE"
  ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE"
  ShowInEditForm="FALSE"
  ShowInListSettings="FALSE"
  ShowInNewForm="FALSE"
  ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE"
  ShowInViewForms="FALSE"
  ...
```

Same is done for _dlc_DocIdUrl and _dlc_DocIdPersistId. But it doesnt work.

[image: I want to hide doc id]

Any idéa how to hide this? I was thinking about using css but there seems to be no way of identify the specific field and the element position will change if adding more columns.